# Orthogonal Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality

Given a set of vectors $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, how can I find a set of orthonormal vectors $\{y_1,\ldots,y_m\colon m\leq n\}$ spanning the same space spanned by $\{x_i\}$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look up [the Gram-Schmidt process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram-Schmidt_Process).